# Flagging outliers of one column based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, outliers

I have a dataframe as shown below where there is an order for each hourminute. Only the first six rows are shown.

| Order | Hourminute |
| --- | --- |
| 120 | 12.15 |
| 150 | 12.15 |
| 7 | 12.15 |
| 20 | 12.30 |
| 200 | 12.30 |
| 23 | 12.30 |

I need help in creating a new column in python called outliers_detected which flags the order outliers based on the hourmin as shown below. This has to be done for every hourminute in a day and not just the two hourminute shown here.

| Order | Hourminute | outliers_detected |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 120 | 12.15 | 0 |
| 150 | 12.15 | 0 |
| 7 | 12.15 | 1 |
| 20 | 12.30 | 0 |
| 150 | 12.30 | 1 |
| 23 | 12.30 | 0 |

Comment: Why order `200` becomes `150` ? Also, can you explain how you define an *outlier*

Comment: An outlier in this case is when you take a specific hourminute and the orders go beyond the 3 or 4 standard deviation for that particular hourminute

Answer (score 0):

Via `Zscore`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

df['outliers_detected'] = df.groupby('Hourminute').transform(
    lambda x: (np.abs(stats.zscore(x)) > 1).astype(int))
```